# Trinity de novo transcriptome assembly: samtools view failed to add PG line to the header

Tags: samtools, transcriptome, trinity

I have assembled the transcriptome a plant species using Trinity.

Here is the command:

```
Trinity --samples_file ./sample_file.txt --seqType fq --max_memory 80G --CPU 30 --output ./trinity_outdir
```

I tried to get transcript abundance using the following command:

```
/home/programs/build/trinityrnaseq/util/align_and_estimate_abundance.pl \
  --transcripts ./Trinity.fasta \
  --seqType fq \
  --samples_file ./sample_file.txt \
  --thread_count 6 \
  --gene_trans_map ./trinity_outdir.Trinity.fasta.gene_trans_map \
  --est_method RSEM \
  --aln_method bowtie2 \
  --prep_reference \
  --coordsort_bam \
  --output_dir /rsem_outdir/
```

And I keep getting the following error:

```
[E::sam_hrecs_update_hashes] Duplicate entry "TRINITY...." in sam header
```

samtools view: failed to add PG line to the header

I will appreciate your suggestions.